# Internet Explorer automation form post

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

I am trying to load a page using vbscript. Then i enter some dummy values in its input fields and try to submit it.

Here is the code for it:

```
    Dim ie
Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate("http://somepage.com")

ie.width = 900
ie.height = 600
ie.Visible = 1

WScript.sleep(5000)

'Home page of user is loaded.
'Now find the field containing mobile number and type message




    Dim nameField, messageField
    set nameField = ie.document.getElementById("MobileNos")'this line throws error
    nameField.value = "somebody"

    messageField = ie.document.getElementById("Message")
    messageField.value = "Hi"

    'Sending the message
    ie.document.frmpostcomment.submit()
```

But whenever I try to run this code doesn't post the comment, instead it just refreshes the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the post of the form I should have written

```
ie.document.frmpostcomment.submitbtn.click
```

This worked for me.